# measure preserving map does not increase distance

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request

I read a sentence saying "any measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can be mapped to an interval by a measure-preserving transformation which does not increase distances" Here the measure is Lebesgue measure and the distance is the standard distance. Is there any reference for this? Thanks!

Comment: If it means "mapped into" rather than "mapped onto", then it's easy to show. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think it means onto, up to a set of measure 0...BTW I guess here measure preserving is only for that specific measurable set, not for every measurable set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, by using something like $f(x)=\arctan x$ (which decreases distances), we can map our set bijectively to a bounded set. For such a set $A\subseteq [a,b]$, we can now apply the map $A\to [0,|A|]$, $x\mapsto |A\cap[a,x]|$, which has the required properties.

Comment: Does f preserve measure? I guess no. But the second map does preserve measure and not increase distance. Can we use $-\infty$ instead of a if A is not bounded? Or moving all points to the origin? Thank you for your answer! It is very helpful!

Comment: No, it doesn't; we're indeed better off mapping $x\mapsto |A\cap (-\infty,x]|$, and now we need to make the extra assumption that $A$ has finite measure.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!